# I want to know how to pass an array of pointer objects into my constructor in C++

Tags: c++, arrays, object, pointers, constructor

In my header file for my PCBTable.cpp I have this:

```
class PCBTable {
private:
PCB* table[];
}
```

In my PCBTable.cpp I am trying to create a constructor that initializes the table to a blank table of PCB objects, with the size of my parameter and it looks like this

```
PCBTable::PCBTable(int size) {
    table = new PCB*[size];
}
```

However I get the error that table must be a modifiable value(E0137), and that array type PCB*[] is not assignable.

I've tried messing around with this but I can't get it to work.

Comment: Tip: Forget this `new[]` stuff and use `std::vector`. If you're slinging bare pointers around, you may want to [wrap those](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr) as well.

Comment: `PCB* table[];` is not valid.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`new T[...]` returns a `T*` pointer, where `T` in your case is `PCB*`, thus you are asking `new[]` to return a `PCB**` pointer, which cannot be assigned to a `PCB*[]` <sup>1</sup> fixed array, hence the error.

(<sup>1</sup> you are not specifying the size of the array, which is invalid syntax)

You need to change your `table` declaration to match what `new[]` actually returns, eg:

```
class PCBTable {
private:
    PCB** table;
    int table_size;
public:
    PCBTable(int size);
    ~PCBTable();
};
```

```
PCBTable::PCBTable(int size) : table_size(size) {
    table = new PCB*[size];
    for (int i = 0; i < size; ++i) {
        table[i] = new PCB;
    }
}

PCBTable::~PCBTable() {
    for (int i = 0; i < table_size; ++i) {
        delete table[i];
    }
    delete[] table;
}
```

Alternatively, if you just need an array of objects, rather than an array of pointers to objects:

```
class PCBTable {
private:
    PCB* table;
    int table_size;
public:
    PCBTable(int size);
    ~PCBTable();
};
```

```
PCBTable::PCBTable(int size) {
    table_size = size;
    table = new PCB[size];
}

PCBTable::~PCBTable() {
    delete[] table;
}
```

That being said, you really should be using `std::vector` instead of `new[]`/`delete[]` manually. And if you are using C++11 or later, use `std::unique_ptr` or `std::shared_ptr` instead of raw pointers, eg:

```
#include <vector>
#include <memory>

class PCBTable {
private:
    std::vector<std::unique_ptr<PCB>> table;
public:
    PCBTable(int size);
};
```

```
PCBTable::PCBTable(int size) : table(size) {
    for (auto &elem : table) {
        elem = std::make_unique<PCB>();
    }
}
```

Or:

```
#include <vector>
#include <memory>

class PCBTable {
private:
    std::vector<PCB> table;
public:
    PCBTable(int size);
};
```

```
PCBTable::PCBTable(int size) : table(size) {
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There seems to be some confusion here. Arrays (declared like `int foo[12]`) are fixed-size at compile time and can be found on the stack. If you want a dynamically sized array, a list whose size is defined at runtime and isn't necessarily known at compile time, that needs to be a pointer. If the elements you want in your array are themselves pointers, it will have to be a pointer to pointers.

```
class PCBTable {
private:
    PCB** table;
}
PCBTable::PCBTable(int size){
    table = new PCB*[size];
}
```

Or, better yet, you could use `std::vector`, which gives you all the best of both worlds.

```
#include <vector>

class PCBTable {
private:
    std::vector<PCB*> table;
}
PCBTable::PCBTable(int size){
    table.resize(size);
}
```

You can use std::vector any way you would use a normal array. This also provides the dual benefit of not having to store the array size in an external variable, as `table.size()` takes care of that for you.